# What determines the consistency of hydrogen foam when reacting aluminium with sodium hydroxide solution?

Tags: hydrogen, explosives, alkali-metals

I was using $\ce{NaOH}$ solution to remove hardened grease from my stove burners, and it began to generate a lot of bubbles, some of which merged into a big bubble and erupted into the surface, but most formed a very thick foam.

I left it reacting for a few minutes and it started making way too much foam, about 3 liters of it.

And then I remembered that the burners were cast aluminum, and this should be $\ce{H2}$ foam.

I took a mere spoonful and set it on fire (far from the main pot where I left it) and it produced a very loud and instantaneous bang with a fast flash instead of a slow and fiery deflagration.

This is worrying, that meant the whole foam had a very good hydrogen and air mix, if the whole thing were to explode it would cause at least a hell of a mess and would scare all my neighbors.

I guess not much $\ce{H2}$ escaped into the room, but I thoroughly ventilated the ceiling to remove any accumulated $\ce{H2}$ just in case (after dissolving all the foam in water).

Then I thought to myself, "Why didn't anyone warn me about this explosive foam? Using $\ce{NaOH}$ solution to dissolve grease is so common here".

But I couldn't find any videos on YouTube where $\ce{NaOH + Al}$ resulted in such an explosive and thick foam as mine.

Instead it just bubbles out of the solution, and setting it on fire never resulted in such a crisp bang.

And when people intentionally made foam, they didn't make it like that, instead they bubbled pure $\ce{H2}$ through a soap solution.

But my solution had no soap. Just $\ce{NaOH}$ and the aluminum pieces.

Am I missing something here?

Did the little soap produced by the reaction with the grease made all of that?